# Bootstrap datetimepicker with hh:mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am working on an application, and I'm a little stuck on the datetimepicker. The datepicker should be able to show a data format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss (year, month and date with current hour, minutes and seconds...). It's working fine, but after when i select the date the datepicker has to autoclose or hide. But it's not going off. I tried a lot with different scripts, still not able to work. Following is the HTML:

```
<span>Select time with Date</span>
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
      <input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker2' />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
```

Following is the JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
       format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
    autoclose: true 
  });
  });
    </script>
```

I guess the script is not supporting autoclose call. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just listen to the datetimepicker [`dp.change`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/) event and force closing the datetimepicker when the date is changed like:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
  });

  // Hide datetimepicker on date change
  $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function() {
    $(this).data("DateTimePicker").hide();
  });

  // Show datetimepicker on input text click
  $('#datetimepicker2 > input').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('.date').data('DateTimePicker').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Its working perfect. Thx. One more thing if you can help me with. Now when i click the icon only the datepicker is appearing. What i need to do if the datepicker has to appear when i click the text box?

Comment: I have updated the post for it. I think it should work fine. Please let me know if it works fine.